# Bug in Excel VBA change text font in cell

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

I made a function to find and replace text in a cell in an excel sheet once replaced it should emphasize the text by making it bold and a specific color. At first it seemed to work, but now I find that in specific cases some weird behavior occurs. It seems that when I start changing the text color at positions other than the first position then random text may be appended at the end. Next to that it seems that excel becomes unstable afterwards.

I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/238092de-f6b8-4439-9276-2d5d6d661dd3/a-huge-bug-when-changing-the-font-of-a-cell-character-in-vba?forum=excel) question in a topic where someone has a very similar issue only then with changing the actual font. From this I found out that the bug can be avoided by always 'touching' the first character. Currently I change the color of the first character in its own color as a work around, but i am not sure that this issue will not pop up later.

Here an images of the cells in excel and the behavior when it goes wrong:

[image: weird outcome]

That's why I was curious if anyone has seen this issue and if there is a clean 'solution' for this.

```
Public Sub Find_and_replace_in_string(CellToEvaluate As Range, ValueToBeFoundAndReplaced As String, Newvalue As String, Mark_updated As Integer)
Dim startchar As Integer
Dim len_input As Integer
Dim len_newvalue As Integer
Dim endchar As Integer
Dim string_input As String
Dim oRange As Excel.Range
Set oRange = CellToEvaluate
startchar = 1 ' init value
len_newvalue = Len(Newvalue)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If oRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    While startchar <> 0
        string_input = oRange.Cells.Value
        startchar = InStr(startchar, string_input, ValueToBeFoundAndReplaced)
        'check if the first character after the match is a comma or en of string
        If startchar <> 0 Then
            endchar = startchar + Len(ValueToBeFoundAndReplaced)
            If Mid(string_input, endchar, 1) = "" Or Mid(string_input, endchar, 1) = "," Then
                len_input = Len(ValueToBeFoundAndReplaced)
                'use replace function in a very specific region to replace the correct part
                With oRange.Characters(Start:=startchar, Length:=len_input)
                    .Text = Newvalue
                End With
                'oRange.Cells.Characters(Start:=startchar, Length:=len_input).Text = Newvalue

                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                ''quick Fix for Issue with randomly changing fonts, if first character is not changed
                'With oRange.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
                '    .ColorIndex = .ColorIndex
                'End With
                '"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""


                If Mark_updated <> 0 Then
                    With oRange.Characters(Start:=startchar, Length:=len_newvalue).Font
                        .Bold = True
                        .ColorIndex = Mark_updated '.ColorIndex + 1
                    End With
                    'oRange.Cells.Characters(Start:=startchar, Length:=len_newvalue).Font.colorindex = Mark_updated
                End If
            End If
            startchar = startchar + len_newvalue
        Else
            startchar = 0
        End If
    Wend
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub test_find_and_replace()
     Dim example_sheet As Excel.Worksheet
     Set example_sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
     Find_and_replace_in_string example_sheet.Cells(3, 1), "one", "111", 3
End Sub
```

kind regards,
Grard