# Excel VBA Bolding red text in a string

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm working on an Excel macro that will loop through cells and bold all text within each that is already formatted as red. Each cell contains a string with automatic black text except for keywords which are highlighted as red. I just want those red keywords to also be bolded.

The way I have it set up now, it iterates through each character individually, which although not the fastest, is fine for my purposes, since it will only be run on a few cells at a time.
I initially had it coded as this:

```
Sub redTxtBold2()
Dim i As Integer

For Each currentCell In Selection
    SearchString = currentCell.Value
    If IsNull(currentCell.Font.ColorIndex) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
            If currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next currentCell
End Sub
```

The problem I ran into here was that, although it worked fine for most cells, in cases where the first character in a cell was red, it would bold that character and remove the red text formatting in the rest of the cell. Figuring out why it does this and preventing it would be the best solution, but I came up with a workaround:

```
Sub redTxtBold1()
Dim i, tstart As Integer
Dim redTxt As String
Dim BoldText As String

For Each currentCell In Selection
    SearchString = currentCell.Value
    If IsNull(currentCell.Font.ColorIndex) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
            If currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                redTxt = redTxt & currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
                Debug.Print redTxt
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    tstart = InStr(currentCell.Text, redTxt)
    Debug.Print tstart
    currentCell.Characters(tstart, Len(redTxt)).Font.Bold = True
    redTxt = ""
Next currentCell
End Sub
```

The problem now with this one is that if the string contains multiple red keywords spaced throughout, redTxt collects and merges them together, causing InStr to not find the substring. The macro thus bolds the first few characters for Len(redTxt) regardless of which are red or not.

I've only been experimenting with VBA for a couple months now, so my skills are still fairly limited. How can I code this better so it bolds all red, and only red characters?

Comment: Why not just make the individual character bold in your If clause? It will be slow code I guess, depending on how much data you are looking at.

Comment: Having checked your first code, that does seem to be an odd bug - it turns the first character bold and then turns it black when it changes the next red character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain the reason.  But here is a workaround that seems to work for the cases you cite.

- Pass through once and collect the character pos of all the cells that are red.
- Then pass through the second time and make all those characters both red and bold

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub redTxtBold2()
Dim i As Integer
Dim currentCell As Range
Dim SearchString As String
Dim Col As Collection, V As Variant

For Each currentCell In Selection
    SearchString = currentCell.Value
    If IsNull(currentCell.Font.ColorIndex) Then
        Set Col = New Collection
        For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
            If currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then _
                    Col.Add i
        Next i
        With currentCell
            For Each V In Col
                .Characters(V, 1).Font.Bold = True
                .Characters(V, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Next V
        End With
    End If
Next currentCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works perfectly. I was wondering if it was possible to collect character positions to modify later but didn't know how to use collections.

Comment: @Danimal There are a variety of ways to store the positions for later processing. I like Collections because I find them easier to use than some of the other methods.  But you could also use arrays, or even a worksheet. I suspect Collections are faster, but I don't have data to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a longstanding bug e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919489/bug-in-excel-vba-change-text-font-in-cell). This workaround, an adaptation of your first go should resolve it even if it is rather inelegant.

```
Sub redTxtBold2()

Dim i As Integer, currentCell As Range, SearchString As String, b As Boolean

For Each currentCell In Selection
    SearchString = currentCell.Value
    If IsNull(currentCell.Font.ColorIndex) Then
        For i = 2 To Len(SearchString)
            If currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                currentCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    If currentCell.Characters(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        currentCell.Characters(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next currentCell

End Sub
```

Comment: It's funny, I actually tried the EXACT same solution earlier. Unfortunately, the problem just continues now with the second character instead of the first.

Comment: Drat, so it does, I hadn't tested that. Anyway you have a working solution now.